# Sinch only show 30 day historic if I wipe app data

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

Is there anyway to show the complete 30 day sinch instant messaging historic on android without have to wipe the app data?
It seems that once I read the messages there's any mechanism that says to not show them again.
Is there any way to prevent this?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sinch is not an inbox, we keep the messages for delivery for 30 days to each device. If you want to keep messages in a login / logout scenario you need to save them in your own backend.